# Min and max properties in scene builder JavaFX do not work

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, resizable

I set min and max properties so that to make my window not resizable. But when I try it out it does not work. What is wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the line:

```
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
```

This will make the window non-resizable, without the need for setting min and max values.

Answer (score 2):

you could simply set the resizable property of your window to false,

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setResizable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
primaryStage.setMaxHeight(A);
primaryStage.setMaxWidth(B);
primaryStage.setMinHeight(A);
primaryStage.setMinWidth(B);
```

Where A and B are doubles.